# Use Mac Shortcuts in Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, shortcuts, windows, windows-7

I use both Windows and OSX on my MacBook Pro.

Due to the nature of the keyboard it's very annoying to run Windows, for example, quite a few of the keys you would usually use are missing on a MBP - end, pageup, etc.

Is it possible to map some of the OSX shortcuts in Windows?  For example, can I map Cmd+C to COPY, Cmd+V to PASTE, Cmd+Right to END, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do all of the above with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source utility for Windows. With it, you can:
>
> Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks. You can write a [mouse or keyboard macro](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Macros.htm) by hand or use the macro recorder.
>
> Create [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Virtually any key, button, or combination can become a hotkey.
>
> [Expand abbreviations](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) as you type them. For example, typing "btw" can automatically produce "by the way".
>
> Create custom data-entry forms, user interfaces, and menu bars. See [GUI](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm) for details.
>
> [Remap](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) keys and buttons on your keyboard, joystick, and mouse.
>
> Respond to signals from hand-held remote controls via the [WinLIRC client script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/WinLIRC.htm).
>
> Run existing AutoIt v2 scripts and enhance them with [new capabilities](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoIt2Users.htm).
>
> Convert any script into an [EXE file](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) that can be run on computers that don't have AutoHotkey installed.